# How to retrieve a 'favicon.ico' image using AJAX when a web site redirects a HTTP request?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, favicon

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.0.9 and jQuery 1.6. [I am using a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215010/trouble-on-retrieving-favicon-ico-images-using-ajax-http-requests) (see the accepted answer) so to retrieve the `favicon.ico` icon image from some web sites.

As you can see all works good except for the `http://www.gmail.com` link for which I get a `301 Moved Permanently` HTTP status response.

[image]

*I would like to improve [this JavaScript code](http://jsfiddle.net/YpBsJ/2/) so to follow the redirection and then try to find the `favicon.ico` icon image on the "redirected" URL.* **How can I improve that code so to correctly retrieve the favicon image?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your JavaScript. If you try going to the favicon.ico in a browser, you'll see that it won't even give you the icon. The 301 Redirect is pointing to http://mail.google.com/mail/, which would just be a G-Mail inbox. There is no image at this location. This was the result from `curl -i`.

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>
> Location: http://mail.google.com/mail/

G-Mail is just trying to take the person to their inbox since there is nothing there. The actual location of G-Mail's favicon.ico is https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/mail_icon_32.png, which is set via a `meta` tag in the HTML source. From G-Mail's source:

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/2/mail_icon_32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

You can read more about that [here](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon).

Comment: Ok, you are right, but if I consider the `http://www.gmail.com` URL the JavaScript code I linked in the question will not retrieve correctly the favicon. It is for this reason that I would like to "follow" the redirection and then try to retrieve the favicon.

Comment: @Backo Follow what? The 301 is redirecting to HTML, not an image. You would have to get the HTML, parse it, extract the meta tag; make the URL an absolute URL, etc. However, none of that is really possible on the client side due to cross-origin-policy.

Comment: Can you make me an example on how you would handle this situation with a JavaScript code implementation? I think you are referring to check (on the *img.onerror* event) if the request is redirected and then parse the HTML code.

Comment: @Backo - the `onerror` of `img` will only tell you if there is an error, it can't be used to get the HTML of where the 301 redirect. That would be way too easy of a way to violate cross-origin-policy.

Comment: So, making a recap (if I have understood everything): the only solution to make the JavaScript code to work as I expect is: *I must provide to the `imageExists` method the `http://mail.google.com/` URL instead of `http://www.gmail.com/`*. No other solution?